# Would it be advised to answer already answered questions - with alternative answers?

Tags: discussion

#### Hello,

Clarified question:

Say we have a question, (solved by a answer) which, might be any (but not limited to) of the following:

- [x] outdated. (Maybe the Question is about a Python 2 problem/issue - and now, we have Python3 - or something similar)
- [x] The problem is - just 1 problem; but (maybe) this problem is followed by sub-problems ? (Sometimes no, sometimes yes - ) Here I thought of maybe - one could add a additional line (maybe at the end of ones answer) "If one gets this / these problem(s) *afterwards* this got solved, one could try (...) (referencing with links, and additional Resources) "

##### Instead of having only 1 answer to 1 question, would it be advised to (even if solved) post alternative solutions?

E.g, if someone had problems with a driver, instead of only letting 1 answer "be the only one" (Not that it is like this, this is just a question! :) )  would it be "okay" or "recommended" to post a solution that worked for one self - but as the other (accepted) solution did not work (not for the one that's asking, but for someone having the same problem)

Would it be recommended to post "other" solutions "to the same problem" ?

I have very often asked myself this, and not really got any good answers.

I hope it is not too fuzzy.

#### Edit: Thanks a lot for answer;  Have a great - **Corona free** Year on you all reading this!

External references

- https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/is-it-advisable-to-provide-a-supplementary-answer-to-a-question
  even though it is for Physics, I still post it, as it could also give some info as well :)

Here is a practical example of something like this I did;

- [Ubuntu boots to black screen with cursor after upgrade (from 18.04 to 20.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279976/ubuntu-boots-to-black-screen-with-cursor-after-upgrade-from-18-04-to-20-04/1279979#1279979)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, definitely. Having a variety of valid answers makes it more likely that people visiting the page will find an answer that works for them.